# Does Firebase Realtime Database Search on a node also download data from sub nodes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two important questions about Firebase Realtime Database (For android with java).

Observe the following structure:

[image]

I have the following class:

```
public class User {
    String name;
    String age;
    String region;
    String color;
}
```

To search the user's data (name, age, region and color), I do:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = ConfigF.getFirebase().child("users").child("user1");
        usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

**Question 1:** when doing this search, does firebase download only the user data (except the message node) or also download the data that is in the message node?

Imagine that there are millions of messages in the messages node, doing this search, will millions of messages be downloaded as well? just why the messaging node is inside the user's node?

I only want the data name, age, region and color, that is, all the attributes that are in the class, can I do the research in this way?

**Question 2:** If I remove the "color" attribute from the User class, when doing the same search above, will the value that is in "color" in the database be downloaded? Or just the data that will be in the class (name, age and region)?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database queries are deep, which means that a request for any node will download **all** children under that node.  There is no way to exclude a certain child.  For that reason, sometimes it makes sense to split related data into different parent nodes, to request only as needed.

Comment: So, for whatever example I mentioned, the only way out is to create a separate node for the messages, correct?

Comment: That's what I recommended, yes.